# What is facility level?

Tags: dragalia-lost

My castle refuses to be upgraded until facility level 100, but I am currently at 59.  How is this calculated?  I tried adding the levels of all my buildings, (14 gold mine + 14 gold mine + 15 dragon tree + 9 fire orb + 9 wind orb + 3 castle) but that comes out to 64.  Even ignoring the castle, it's 61.  What all goes into calculating facility level?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Dragalia Lost Wiki](https://dragalialost.gamepedia.com/Facilities):

> The Facility Level is the sum of the levels of all facilities, except for decorative facilities. Halidom and Smithy levels also contribute to the facility level.

You may have been calculating decorative facilities also.